# When do I need to use password_needs_rehash()?

Tags: php, authentication, php-password-hash

I have a processing file for a login to an app. I either do not understand the purpose of `password_needs_rehash()` or it is not working. The login is authenticating and passing me through to the correct page. But I can't get the code to even echo the new hash.

Am I doing this correctly?

Does the `if` not throw a new hash because it does not need rehashed? If so when would a password need rehashed if it was properly hashed and stored in the DB?

My processing file is below:

```
$hash = $row['hash'];
$userPassword = $_POST["li_password"];
if (password_verify($userPassword, $hash)) {
    if ( password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]) ) {
        $newhash = password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
        echo $newhash;
    }
} else {
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '?error=loginfailed');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It needs a rehash if you change the `cost`.

Comment: I see. NOOB QUESTION: why would i want to change the cost? and if I do wouldn't it not rehash once the `user` logs in the first time since the cost of the new hash would be changed? OR do I want to randomize the cost?

Comment: The more the `cost` the more CPU time it takes to convert a raw password into the hash that can be used to validate the password. The more cost, the more difficult it becomes to "crack" it. So why you want to change it? Well, perhaps by the time CPU speed is increased or perhaps you moved to a cloud where multiple CPU's do the same thing and the load is balanced. Either way, `10` is plenty.

Comment: OK so its a future proofing piece of code? Like its 2 years from now CPUs have gotten faster meaning the cost I set is less secure now I up the cost to advance with the times?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Dont need to change code or anything, just verify at login if it needs a rehash and change the cost at your own discretion.

Comment: Presumably also if the value of `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` changes in a new version of PHP, @Xorifelse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`password_needs_rehash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) only needs to be used if you change the `$options` which usually refers to the `cost`.

The more the cost, the more CPU time it takes to hash the password but the more difficult it becomes to crack it. If you change hosting or move over to a cloud based system where multiple computers can calculate the hash for you, you are able to increment it at your own discretion.

You only need to check if the password needs a rehash at user login, since [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) can still verify the password if you changed the `$options`. If [`password_needs_rehash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) returns true at that point, use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with the new options and replace the old hash.

```
if (password_verify($_POST["li_password"], $row['hash'])) {
    // valid login

    if (password_needs_rehash($row['hash'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options = ['cost' => 12])) {
        $newhash = password_hash($_POST["li_password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
        // store new hash in db.
    }
} else {
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '?error=loginfailed');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You may want to check my answer, just out of curiosity

Comment: Thanks for the edit @YourCommonSense, it seems I keep forgetting `execute()` only accepts an array of values instead of a `...$packed` argument list from my API. And yes, your code does looks cleaner without error checking obviously. Only added it to add some "sense" to it.